# Differential of a smooth map on holomorphic tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

If $f : M \to N$ is a smooth map between complex manifolds $M$, $N$ then the  differential map $df: T_{\mathbb{R},p} \to T_{\mathbb{R},f(p)}$ is a linear map betweeen real tangent spaces and by complexification of this real linear map we have a complex linear map between complex tangent spaces $df: T_{\mathbb{C},p} \to T_{\mathbb{C},f(p)}$. I read in a book that this complex linear map in general does not take the holomorphic tangent space $T_p'M$ to $T_{f(p)}'M$, but why?

In fact, a map $f : M \to N$ is holomorphic if and only if $df_p(T_p'M) \subset T_{f(p)}'N$ but I am not getting why holomorphicity of $f$ is needed for $df_p(T_p'M) \subset T_{f(p)}'N$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the smooth map $\operatorname{conj}:M=\mathbb C\to N=\mathbb C:z\mapsto \bar z$.
Its differential $d\operatorname{conj}_p$ sends $\frac {\partial}{\partial z}|_p$ to $\frac {\partial}{\partial \bar z}|_p$ and thus sends $T'_p=\mathbb C\cdot \frac {\partial}{\partial z} |_p$ onto $T''_p=\mathbb C\cdot \frac {\partial}{\partial \bar z} |_p$ and not into $T'_p=\mathbb C\cdot \frac {\partial}{\partial z}|_p$. Thus we don't have $d\operatorname{conj}_p(T'_p)\subset T'_p$ .

Notice carefully that $d\operatorname{conj}_p$ is $\mathbb C$-linear for the formal complex structure  arising from the definition of $T_{\mathbb C,p}$ as $T_{\mathbb C,p}=T_{\mathbb R,p}\otimes_\mathbb R \mathbb C$, but not for the complex structure arising from the structure of $\mathbb C$ as a complex manifold: the multiplication of $\frac {\partial}{\partial x}$ by $i$ for those structures yields respectively $i\frac {\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac {\partial}{\partial y}$.